# Solving $ y'' + a y = f(x) $ with zero initial conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, convolution, initial-value-problems

> Given the following initial value problem (IVP) $$ y'' + a y = f(x), \qquad  y(0)= y'(0) = 0$$ show that $$y = \frac1a \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin(ax-at)\ {\rm d}t$$

---

**My attempt**

To solve the given initial value problem $$y''+ay=f(x)$$ we first solve the homogeneous equation $$y''+ay=0$$ The characteristic equation is $r^2+a=0$, which has roots $r=\pm\sqrt{-a}$. Depending on the sign of $a$, these roots can be written as complex numbers or real numbers.

If $a<0$, we can write the roots as $r=\pm i\sqrt{a}$. In this case, the general solution to the homogeneous equation is $$y_h(x) = c_1\cdot \cos\sqrt{-a}x + c_2\sin\sqrt{-a}x$$

If $a>0$, we can write the roots as $r=±\sqrt(a)$. In this case, the general solution to the homogeneous equation is $$y_h(x) = c_1\cdot e^{-\sqrt{a}x)} + c_2e^{\sqrt{a}x}$$

Proceeding as such only the former case yields the correct result. What about the latter?

Comment: Are you acquainted with the convolution?

Comment: If you are familiar with the Laplace Transfrom then you can easily use it to get the result. A bonus would be to read up on the convolution integral...

Comment: Unfortunately I am not exactly familiar with those concepts. Is there a solution involving basic calculus and is my approach wrong?

Comment: The corresponding homogeneous equation - obtained when $f=0$ - has only the solution $0$, your constants $c_1,c_2$ vanish. Now we have a term breaking the linearity. Do we have still propositions that insure uniqueness of the solution? (If this is the case, it is enough to *check* the claimed solution. Which is easily done. To see the uniqueness, consider the difference of two solutions.)

Comment: What is the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of $f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you show is actually wrong. Here is the correct one. The $a$ is the final solution should be $\sqrt a$.

$$
y^{\prime\prime}+ay=f(x)
$$

The solution to $y_{h}$ is $c_{1}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  +c_{2}%
\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  $. Hence the basis solutions are $y_{1}%
=\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  ,y_{2}=\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  $. $y_{p}$
is found using variation of parameters. Let

$$
y_{p}=u_{1}y_{1}+u_{2}y_{2}
$$

Where
\begin{align*}
u_{1}  & =-\int\frac{y_{2}f\left(  x\right)  }{W}dx\\
u_{2}  & =\int\frac{y_{1}f\left(  x\right)  }{W}dx
\end{align*}

Where Wronskian is

$$
W=
\begin{vmatrix}
y_{1} & y_{2}\\
y_{1}^{\prime} & y_{2}^{\prime}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)   & \sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \\
-\sqrt{a}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)   & \sqrt{a}\cos\left(  \sqrt
{a}x\right)
\end{vmatrix}
=\sqrt{a}\cos^{2}\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  +\sqrt{a}\sin^{2}\left(  \sqrt
{a}x\right)  =\sqrt{a}
$$
Hence
$$
u_{1}=-\int\frac{\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  f\left(  x\right)  }{\sqrt{a}
}dx=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(
t\right)  dt
$$

And

$$
u_{2}=\int\frac{\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  f\left(  x\right)  }{\sqrt{a}
}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{x}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(
t\right)  dt
$$

Therefore

\begin{align*}
y  & =c_{1}y_{1}+c_{2}y_{2}+u_{1}y_{1}+u_{2}y_{2}\\
& =c_{1}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  +c_{2}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)
-\left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(
t\right)  dt\right)  \cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  +\left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}
}\int_{0}^{x}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  dt\right)
\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)
\end{align*}

At $x=0$ the above becomes.

$$
0=c_{1}
$$

The solution becomes

$$
y=c_{2}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  +\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\left(  \sin\left(
\sqrt{a}x\right)  \int_{0}^{x}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)
dt-\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)
f\left(  t\right)  dt\right)
$$

Taking derivative gives

\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}=c_{2}\sqrt{a}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  +\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}
}\left(  \frac{d}{dx}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \int_{0}^{x}\cos\left(
\sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  dt-\frac{d}{dx}\cos\left(  \sqrt
{a}x\right)  \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)
dt\right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}

But
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  dt  &
=\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  f\left(  x\right)  \\
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  dt  &
=\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  f\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}

Hence (2) becomes

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}  & =c_{2}\sqrt{a}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \\
& +\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\left(  \sqrt{a}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \int
_{0}^{x}\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  dt+\sin\left(
\sqrt{a}x\right)  \cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  f\left(  x\right)  +\sqrt
{a}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)
f\left(  t\right)  dt+\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt
{a}x\right)  f\left(  x\right)  \right)
\end{align*}

At $x=0$ the above gives

$$
0=c_{2}\sqrt{a}
$$

Hence $c_{2}=0$. Therefore the solution is

\begin{align*}
y  & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\left(  \sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)  \int_{0}^{x}
\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  dt-\cos\left(  \sqrt
{a}x\right)  \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)
dt\right)  \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{x}\left[  \sin\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)
\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  -\cos\left(  \sqrt
{a}x\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  f\left(  t\right)  \right]  dt\\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{x}f\left(  t\right)  \left[  \sin\left(
\sqrt{a}x\right)  \cos\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  -\cos\left(  \sqrt{a}x\right)
\sin\left(  \sqrt{a}t\right)  \right]  dt
\end{align*}

Using
$$
\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B=\sin\left(  A-B\right)
$$

Then

\begin{align*}
y  & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{x}f\left(  t\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt
{a}x-\sqrt{a}t\right)  dt\\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{x}f\left(  t\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt
{a}\left(  x-t\right)  \right)  dt
\end{align*}

ps. One can jump to $y_p$ directly in this problem, since we know that if all initial condition are zero, then $y_h$ will be zero, which means $c_1,c_2$ must be zero and the solution is made up only of $y_p$.

Comment: (+1)  I think that the original DE should be $y'' + a^2 y = f(x)$